# How to insert decimal places into linked text file as format

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, text-files, linked-tables

So I have a text file that I am linking to my Access database. The text file is fixed width and there is a large chunk of numbers like 002323002344012345002344000234003456 which is really divided up into individual bits of data like: 002323 002344 012345 002344 000234 003456. I have this set up fine in the advanced section of the link text wizard and set up under "Specs". The problem is, the data is supposed to include two decimal places for all of these numbers (which for some reason gets lost when the text file is created elsewhere) and is supposed to read like: 0023.23 0023.44 0123.45 0023.44 0002.34 0034.56. Is there some way to format this correctly through the template, or am I stuck having to copy the 1mil+ records into a different table in order to format these numbers correctly?

Comment: Can't you just create a query which divides the values of those linked fields by 100, and whenever you need to use the linked data, use the query?

Comment: Well I could do that, but it would be too easy... I would still like to know if it's possible without a query just out of curiosity, but that definitely works for my situation.

Comment: Another option would be to use your existing Import Specification to create a Linked Table to the text file, then use an Append Query or a Make-Table query to divide the numbers by 100 when you insert them into the actual table.